# Woocommerce digital product hosted on Amazon S3 - do I NEED to buy the integration plugin?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Woocommerce is famous for overpriced and semi-useless extensions and S3 has massive configurability. So since I have very little experience both and didn't find any online tutorial I am wondering does woocommerce force you to buy the extension to integrate it with shortcodes or does it just save you time in not having to secure your files in S3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the future the plugin is completely unnecesary just configure S3 privacy and you are good to go.